# How to change UTC Unicode into Epoch w/Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, utc, epoch

I'm trying to convert UTC Unicode such as:

```
Fri 26 May 2017 20:00:00 +0000
```

and turn it into epoch, in the simplest way possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with datetime:

```
epoch = (datetime.datetime(2017,05,26,20,0) - datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds()
```

or

```
epoch = datetime.datetime(2017,05,26,20,0).strftime('%s')
```